# unable to load rsa public key if it's created using c++

Tags: openssl, rsa

I created rsa key pair in c++ using RSA_generate_key method and write public key to a separate file. When I tried to encrypt a text using that public key through commandline, I'am getting "Unable to load public key" error. Please some one help me on this...

command used for encryption

```
openssl rsautl -encrypt -inkey public.pem -in myfile.txt -out file.ssl
```

function used to generate keys

```
RSA_generate_key(1024,3,0,0);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I created rsa key pair in c++ using `RSA_generate_key` method and write public key to a separate file.

`RSA_generate_key` creates a key pair. What did you use to write the key to a file?

---

> openssl rsautl -encrypt -inkey public.pem -in myfile.txt -out file.ssl
>
> I'am getting "Unable to load public key" error.

According to the OpenSSL docs on [rsautil(1)](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/rsautl.html):

```
-inkey file

    the input key file, by default it should be an RSA private key.
```

You need to use `-pubin`:

```
-pubin

    the input file is an RSA public key.
```

---

> function used to generate keys: `RSA_generate_key(1024,3,0,0);`

You should use `RSA_generate_key_ex`. See the OpenSSL docs on [RSA_generate_key(3)](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/RSA_generate_key.html).

Comment: Actually I was writting to a file just like any other char array, So it was failing.now I am using PEM_write_PUBKEY(), It's working fine.

Please dnt mind for asking another question here....
Now I have a base64 encoded string encrypted data, I decode it using BIO_f_base64() and stored on to char array(buffer). when I use that buffer for decrypting, RSA_private_decrypt() throwing "-1". Could please Help me on this.......

Comment: Be sure to save the private key too with `PEM_write_PrivateKey`. Otherwise, you won't be able to decrypt the message later.

Comment: I stored private key using PEM_write_PrivateKey function to pri.key.
I did echo "base64encodedstring" | base64 --decode >> a.txt and used pri.key to decrypt it using command line. it was working fine.but by using RSA_private_decrypt()function unable to decrypt. If u need I will post my code.

Comment: Ask it as a separate question. State what you have done so far.

Comment: "RSA_private_decrypt() is returning -1" - Try calling `ERR_get_error()` to see why its failing.